# Unset all session variables with similar name

Tags: php, session, session-variables, unset

I'm using some `$_SESSION` variables for filtering many query records that have a similar name (ex. `$_SESSION['nameFilter']` or `$_SESSION['cityFilter']` and so on).

I'm using a link for resetting these filters, but I want to know if there is a way to unset all `$_SESSION` variables that have a name that is like:

`$_SESSION[(somewords)Filter]`

Comment: Loop through session, and you could check if the key contains Filter, if it does unset it?

Comment: You should switch to a multidimensional array if this is a requirement: `$_SESSION['filter']['name']`, `$_SESSION['filter']['city']`, etc. Then you just have to unset the parent element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to enumerate [the keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) of `$_SESSION[]`, use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get the last 6 characters of each key, use [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) to (what else?) unset it.

As easy as:

```
session_start();
foreach (array_keys($_SESSION) as $key) {
    if (substr($key, -6) == 'Filter') {
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Steps :**

```
1.) Get all session variable using $_SESSION.
2.) Check in every session key if it contain "Filter" string 
then unset it using unset($_SESSION[(someword)Filter]);
```

**Try this :**

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value){
  if (strstr($key, 'Filter') == 'Filter') {
    unset($_SESSION[$key]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your keys always cointain the string `Filter` you can check for it.

I suggest you to take a look at the [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function which checks if a given needle is cointaned in a string and returns the `null` in case it's not found or the position of where the needle starts in that string.

Then you only have to go through the session variables and unset the ones containing the word `Filter`

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value){
  if (strpos($key, 'Filter') !== false) {
    unset($_SESSION[$key]);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for every exist session and check it name. Please check below example code.

```
<?php
session_start();

//Example records...
$_SESSION['onefilter'] = 'one';
$_SESSION['twofilter'] = 'two';
$_SESSION['threefilter'] = 'three';
$_SESSION['fourtilter'] = 'four';

//Loop untill exist session...
foreach($_SESSION AS $sessKey => $sessValue){
    //Check for session name exist with 'filter' text...
    if (strpos($sessKey, 'filter') !== false) {
        unset($_SESSION[$sessKey]);//Unset session
    }
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . '</pre>';
/*Output...

Array
(
    [fourtilter] => four
)
*/
?>
```

May this help you well.